# How to sort values using dates as keys on Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am trying to make a to do list, and everytime a user checks a checkbox it adds a true/false to the corresponding date. The problem is firebase doesnt sort dates Strings, so after some research I found that I have to use timeInMillis, but Firebase doesnt allow keys other than Strings... 
[image: Database snapshot]

This is how I retrieve the dates..

```
habitosQuery.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            mHabitosList.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot habitosSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Habitos habitos = habitosSnapshot.getValue(Habitos.class);

                Checks = habitos.getChecks();
                Map<String, Boolean> sortedChecks = new TreeMap<>(Checks);
                List<Map.Entry<String, Boolean>> entryList =
                        new ArrayList<>(sortedChecks.entrySet());
                Map.Entry<String, Boolean> lastEntry =
                        entryList.get(entryList.size() - 1);

                try {
                    lastDateEntry = sdf.parse(lastEntry.getKey());

                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Date today = focus.getToday();
                int diffLastToday = focus.daysBetween(lastDateEntry, today);

                for (int x = 0; x < diffLastToday; x++) {
                    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                    calendar.setTime(lastDateEntry);
                    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, +1);
                    Checks.put(sdf.format(calendar.getTimeInMillis()), false);
                }

                habitos.setChecks(Checks);
                mHabitosList.add(habitos);
                mHabitosAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                habitosQuery.child(habitos.getHabitosId()).child("checks").setValue(Checks);

            }
```

Comment: I don't actually understand the problem with using time in milliseconds as keys. Can't be they represented using strings?

Comment: You are right you just add a + "" at the end of the long value, another problem surged now though, How do you get the specific key to update the value?, since timeStamps are constantly changing

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to do it, here is how I did it...
First you have to get your days in a millisecond String, I created this method for that:

```
public String[] getPreviousFiveDays()  {    
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        String dates[] = new String[5];
        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 0 );
        dates[0] = cal.getTimeInMillis()+"";
        for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++){
            cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,-1);
            dates[i] = cal.getTimeInMillis()+"";
        }
        return dates;
    }
```

Then since I wanted to save and modify the dates I created a HashMap on the Object..

```
   private Map<String, Boolean> mChecks;
public Map<String, Boolean> getChecks() {
    return mChecks;
}

public void setChecks(Map<String, Boolean> checks) {
    mChecks = checks;
}
```

Then to modify the dates when the CheckBox was checked I retrieved the keys like this (Since I just used the last five keys, I only retrieved those):

```
 mChecks = new TreeMap<>(habitos.getChecks());

        List<Map.Entry<String, Boolean>> entryList =
                new ArrayList<>(mChecks.entrySet());
        for (int x=0; x<5; x++) {
            int y = 1 + x;
            Map.Entry<String, Boolean> entry =
                    entryList.get(entryList.size() - y);
            mDays[x] = entry.getKey();

        }
```